# Issue with adding a new animation to the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text which appears when I run `contrastShow` function like this:

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastHide() {
  //sfxPlay(sfx.caption_hide);
  contrast.classList.add("contrastHide");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastShow");
}

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("This is the text");

setTimeout(() => {
    contrast.classList.add("zoomIn");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5vh; /*top: 82vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contrast {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contrastShow {
    animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.contrastHide {
    animation: contrastAnimeHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 4vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeHide {
  0%    { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
  100%  { opacity: 0; top:  4vh }
}


.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
          animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
            transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class ="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
        <p id="contrast" class="contrast"></p>
</div>
```

Then I want to animate the text by adding a new class attached to a keyframe animation (using a setTimeout at the very end f the code).

But unexpectedly the text just hides and there is no animation ?!

What I missed and how to fix this?

Comment: By adding that class, you are of course overwriting the `animation` value that was previously set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heartbeat animation is running, your element is just hidden via opacity. You should set the initial value of `.contrast` opacity to `1` and use the `backwards` fill-mode. This way it doesn't fallback to `0` if you overwrite the animation.

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastHide() {
  //sfxPlay(sfx.caption_hide);
  contrast.classList.add("contrastHide");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastShow");
}

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("This is the text");

setTimeout(() => {
    contrast.classList.add("zoomIn");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5vh; /*top: 82vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contrast {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1.2vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contrastShow {
    animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards ;
}

.contrastHide {
    animation: contrastAnimeHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: backwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 4vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeHide {
  0%    { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
  100%  { opacity: 0; top:  4vh }
}


.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
          animation: heartbeat 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
            transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
            transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class ="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
        <p id="contrast" class="contrast"></p>
</div>
```